# Cannot make Angular sanitize / ng-bind-html to work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sanitize

I'm trying to understand the issue with my code for a day without success. So I would ask for help. I'm trying to use ng-bind-html-unsafe in a template. I'm new to Angular so probably I'm missing something simple.
Just to be clear: I did read all related questions / answers first but still stuck.
Here is the code:
http://plnkr.co/edit/AcBeML?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since angular 1.2.x you just have to use `ng-bind-html`

So :

```
ng-bind-html="item.text"
```

Working plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/CLet6FdaxVE9aDKMrqP7?p=preview

Comment: @antgraf you should use $sce for unsafe html... maybe ng-bind-html is not enough for you...

Comment: @wickY26 looks like proposed solution works for me. But as I've said I'm newb so probably I'm missing something. Could you please explain briefly when I need more complex approach with $sce? It is hard to get it from documentation. Thank you.